# Unity Container Resolve in Background Thread

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism, unity-container, backgroundworker

I have an event subscription from PRISM in Background Thread. After Login I load several Application related Data.
Also I try to resolve the MainMenu from Unity Container.

```
MainMenu mainMenu = container.Resolve<MainMenu>();
```

This will end with an exception. It must be called from an STA Thread because the operations are GUI related.
This seems totally understandable, but

1. If I use the Dispatcher there is no Exception but it blocks the UI Thread, thats not what I want.
2. Using another BackgroundWorker or Task Factory wont solve the problem, because its still in background Thread.

So how do I load GUI related stuff inside a background Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a thread with the `STA` ApartmentState:

```
Thread uiThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    mainMenu = container.Resolve<MainMenu>();

    // Allow the main UI thread to proceed 
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();     
});               
uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
uiThread.IsBackground = true;
uiThread.Start();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It is loading the menu correctly. But now i cant assign the menu to my Region, because they are owned by differend threads. How to solve this? :)
`buttonsRegion.Add(mainMenu, "MainMenu");`

Comment: See if this helps [move objects between threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954089/c-sharp-multi-threading-move-objects-between-threads)

Comment: Hmmm still not working `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<MainMenu>((menu) =>
     buttonsRegion.Add(menu, "MainMenu")
    ), new object[] { mainMenu });`